# Integrating Flow Blockchain in Flutter

Tags: flutter, blockchain, nft, cadence, onflow-cadence

I am trying to develop a dAPP using the [Flow Blockchain](https://www.onflow.org/) in Flutter. I cannot find any library or package that I can use to do so. Is this even possible in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You could use flutters HTTP library to make requests to Flows [REST API](https://docs.onflow.org/http-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I started to work on a [Flow Dart SDK](https://github.com/MaxStalker/flow-dart-sdk) quite a long time ago.
The REST API was not available at that time, but you could still do calls via GRPC requests. Check it out - maybe it's something you would be interested in collaborating and we can bring it to finished state.